# Best workflow for both google HTML5 banner ads and animated GIFs

Tags: animation, workflow, gif, html

We have recurrent product campaigns and we are moving on to HTML5 banner ads from just plain GIFs but we are still keeping both formats as some of our target audience is on old systems.

I am looking for the best workflow for making the banners in order to save time and not do the same things twice.

The banners I am making are in 7 different sizes. I am aware of the responsive format but these banners are a bit too complex for them to resize properly so I am sticking to fixed size for now.

I used Google Web Designer for the first HTML5 banner and getting the hang of it but I would like to find a way to convert the final to Gif as well.

Comment: This is a bit broad for StackExchange. It's better suited for a forum like [the GreenSock banner ad forum](https://greensock.com/forums/forum/12-banner-animation/) (disclaimer: I currently work for GreenSock).

Answer (score 1):

You could create your animation in Google Web Designer and then use a screen recording app to capture the animation as a GIF. I do not think you can export as a gif from Google Web Designer.

Another option is using a program that can both create animated HTML5 banners and can also export as a GIF like Adobe Animate.

Comment: or bannersnack, it does exactly that: fixed sizes that can be exported as GIF.